Generate a table of elements whose number is equal to prime numbers
I have a list of words (strings) same as
list = {"resident",  "occupant",  "tenant",  "resider",  "inhabiter",  "habitant",  "dweller",  "citizen",  "native",  "denizen",  "aborigine"};

with 11 elements.
I want to insert them in a 4*3 table with an empty cell (of course) with the below syntax
grid = Grid[Partition[list, 4], Dividers -> All] // Text

But my command is not correct how can I modify this command?

Use UpTo
list =
  {"resident", "occupant", "tenant", "resider", "inhabiter", 
   "habitant", "dweller", "citizen", "native", "denizen", 
   "aborigine"};

Grid[Partition[list, UpTo @ 4], Dividers -> All]



Use Multicolumn
Multicolumn[list, 4, Dividers -> All]


or
Multicolumn[list, 4, Dividers -> All, Appearance -> "Horizontal" ]



Use TableView and Framed:
f = TableView[#, AllowedDimensions -> Reverse@Dimensions@#, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"Frame"}] &;

Framed[f@Partition[Append[list, ""], 4], 
FrameStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3], Red}, FrameMargins -> None]


